# Django taggit query error: must be "model_name" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-taggit

I have a very simple Photo class which uses django_taggit

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ... some other fields
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

Oddly enough, even simple query like this:

```
blue_tag = Tag.objects.get(name='blue')
q1 = Photo.objects.filter(tags=blue_tag)
some_tags = Tag.objects.filter(name__icontains='b')
q1 = Photo.objects.filter(tags__in=some_tags)
```

will result in the following error....

```
Cannot query "blue": Must be "Photo" instance.
```

Which is odd...given the fact that I'm passing Tag objects...

Answer (score 0):

Well... I just reinstalled the all package forcing an upgrade like so

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall django-taggit
```

when doing so be carefull in faking migrations

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

So you do preserve the DB.

Hope is can be helpful to others